# render dots between path segments in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I have a data template (below) for drawing some paths in my application. The paths are made of line and arc segments and draw fine. I'm wondering if there is some way I can draw little dots or separators marking the segment boundaries of the path. How would I modify the template to do that?

I can expose the segment endpoints as its own collection, but I'm not sure how to bind that to a rendering of dot objects.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="assignmentTemplate" DataType="models:AssignmentViewModel">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Converters:MultiplyConverter x:Key="multiplier"/>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Path Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Composition:IWorldAndScreen}}, Path=MetersPerPixel,
                Converter={StaticResource multiplier}, ConverterParameter=2.0}" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeStartLineCap="Square">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures}"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </DataTemplate>
```